# Opening a text file to read in Windows from idLE (Python)

Tags: python

I want to read a file which is on my drive at location `C:\Users\PITA SHIVAYA\Desktop\BIGDATA\test.txt`. How can I run so that I can use this `.txt` file as input for above code.

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin: 
    line = line.strip()
    items = line.split(' ')
    print((str)(items[2] + "\t" + items[4] + "\t" + items[6] + "\t" + items[9] + "\t1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the code ? You can open your file instead of using stdin

```
file_path = r'C:\Users\PITA SHIVAYA\Desktop\BIGDATA\test.txt'

with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    for line in file: 
        line = line.strip()
        items = line.split(' ')
        print((str)(items[2] + "\t" + items[4] + "\t" + items[6] + "\t" + items[9] + "\t1"))
```

Not that I use a raw string for file_path (a `r`before the opening quote), to avoid backslashes to be interpreted as special characters

Another solution is to redirect the file to stdin when you execute python:

```
python my_file.py < C:\Users\PITA SHIVAYA\Desktop\BIGDATA\test.txt
```